# How can I extend BinCounts to work on Times and Dates?

Tags: algorithm, visualization

I want to extend BinCounts to work on a list of times or dates, binning them by Day, Week, Hour of the Month, Day of the Year, etc... So given a list of times and a time bin spec, I need to calculate the bin counts.

One example might be if I have list of times I've been on Facebook and I want to to plot these times on a 2D Histogram where the Y axis is "MinuteOfTheDay" and the x axis is "DayOfTheWeek". Alpha can already do this (but not with arbitrary time bins)

[image]

To clarify my question I made a prototype:

```
d = RandomDates[1000];
Timing[TimeBinCounts[d, {"Day", "Week"}]]
```

gives the proper counts {157, 150, 136, 147, 149, 129, 132}, (e.g. Count[DayOfWeek /@ d, Monday] == 157). And queries like

```
Timing[TimeBinCounts[d, {"Month", "Year"}]]
```

work too, but I'm not sure how to handle an arbitrary time bin spec like "HoursOfTheWeek"

```
Timing[TimeBinCounts[d, {"Hour", "Week"}]]
```

Will not work...

```
<<Calendar`
TimeBinCounts::badspec = "The time bin spec `1` is not acceptable.";
DaysOfTheWeek = {Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday, Sunday};
daysNum = Thread[Rule[DaysOfTheWeek, Range[7]]];
RandomDateList[] := {RandomInteger[{1800, 2100}], RandomInteger[{1, 12}], RandomInteger[{1, 28}], RandomInteger[{0, 23}], RandomInteger[{0, 59}], RandomInteger[{0, 59}]};
RandomDates[n_] := Table[RandomDateList[],{n}]

TimeSpecHelper[spec_] := Module[
    {types, convert, result},
    types = {"Second", "Minute", "Hour", "Day", "Week", "Month", "Year"};
    convert = {60, 60, 24, 7, 4.345, 12};
    result = Range[Times @@ Part[convert, Most[Range @@ Flatten[
        First[Position[types, #]]& /@ spec]]]];
    If[MatchQ[spec[[1]], "Second"|"Minute"|"Hour"],
        result - 1,
        result
    ]
]

TimeBinCounts[times_List, spec_] := Module[
    {dayorder, bins, minDate, maxDate, order},

    minDate = Min[times[[All, 1]]];
    maxDate = Max[times[[All, 1]]];

    order = Thread[Rule[{"Second", "Minute", "Hour", "Day", "Week", "Month", "Year"}, Range[7]]];
    If[Greater @@ (spec /. order),
        Message[TimeBinCounts::badspec, spec];
        Return[$Failed];
    ];

    Switch[spec,
    {"Day","Week"} | "Day",
        With[{days = DayOfWeek /@ times /. daysNum},
        BinCounts[days, {1, 8, 1}]],
    {"Hour", "Day"}|"Hour",
        BinCounts[times[[All, 4]], {0, 24, 1}],
    {"Day", "Month"},
        BinCounts[times[[All, 3]], {1, 32, 1}],
    {"Month", "Year"}|"Month",
        BinCounts[times[[All, 2]], {1, 13, 1}],
    "Year",
        With[{interval = Range[minDate[[1]], maxDate[[1]]]},
            Count[times[[All, 1]], #]& /@ interval
        ],
    _,  
        order = Thread[Rule[{"Second", "Minute", "Hour", "Day", "Month", "Year"}, 
            Range[6]]];
        With[{interval = TimeSpecHelper[spec]},
            Count[Mod[times[[All, 6 - (spec[[1]] /. order) + 1]], Length[interval]], #]& /@ TimeSpecHelper[spec]
    ]
]
]
```

Comment: `GatherBy` might be what you need.

Comment: It will be a lot more involved than just using that GatherBy, what is needed is the temporal analogue of BinCounts, TimeBinCounts.

Comment: I haven't got time to test this out now but indeed `GatherBy` is not enough on its own. But something like `{First[#],Last[#]}& @@@ GatherBy[data,datespec]` might work.

Comment: The time compelxity of GatherBy is too high, this needs to work on 100,000s of dates.

Comment: I deleted my answer, so commenting here: the main bottleneck of your current implementation is in the `DayOfWeek` function, and [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/7125/faster-alternatives-for-dayofweek/7126#7126) I show one possible way to significantly speed it up with the help of Java.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a complete solution, but perhaps it has some ideas that you can work into something usable.

Use `GatherBy` to organise the dates into lists of dates with common parts in Years, Months, Days, Hours, Minutes:

```
dates = ToDate /@ Range[10^8, 10^8 + 3600 24 1000, (3600 24)/400];

arranged=GatherBy[dates, {#[[1]] &, #[[2]] &, #[[3]] &, #[[4]] &, #[[5]] &}];
```

`arranged` took about 3/4 of  a second to construct with about 400,000 dates.

To count the dates in specific years, days, hours, mins etc something like this ...

```
Length@Position[arranged, {1903, 3, 4, _, _, _}]
```

> 238

gives the count for a day.

This gives bin counts for hours for a day:

```
Length@Position[arranged, {1903, 3, 4, #, _, _}] & /@ Range@24
```

> {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 17, 17, 16, 17, 17, 16, 17, 17, 16, 17, 
>   17, 16, 17, 17, 0}

*It just occurred to me that you don't really need to use* `gather` *for this approach:*

```
Length@Position[dates, {1903, 3, 4, #, _, _}] & /@ Range@24
```

> {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 17, 17, 16, 17, 17, 16, 17, 17, 16, 17, 
>   17, 16, 17, 17, 0}

gives exactly the same output.

Maybe the task can be re-cast as creating suitable patterns to select the bins you need, or bins which form the elements of your range and then summing them.