# Faster Alternatives to DateDifference

Tags: performance-tuning, algorithm, date-and-time

I need a faster implementation of `FractionOfYear` and `FractionOfMonth`, which do the following:

**Input:** A time/date specified by `{y_, m_, d_, h_, n_, s_}`

**Output:** A real number from 0 to 1 representing the fraction of the year or month that the given time/date spec occurs in.

Leap days and leap seconds complicate things, so I thought I could just rely on `DateDifference`, but it is too slow:

```
RandomDateList[] := {RandomInteger[{1800, 2100}], RandomInteger[{1, 12}], RandomInteger[{1, 28}], RandomInteger[{0, 23}], RandomInteger[{0, 59}], RandomInteger[{0, 59}]};
RandomDates[n_] := Table[RandomDateList[],{n}]

secondOfYear[{y_, m_, d_, h_, n_, s_}] := 
   First[DateDifference[{y - 1, 12, 31, 24, 0, 0}, {y, m, d, h, n, s}, 
               "Second"]] / First[DateDifference[{y - 1, 12, 31, 24, 0, 0}, {y, 12, 31, 24, 0, 0}, "Second"]]

secondOfMonth[{y_, m_, d_, h_, n_, s_}] := First[DateDifference[{y, m, 1, 0, 0, 0}, 
{y, m, d, h, n, s}, "Second"]]/First[DateDifference[{y, m, 1, 0, 0, 0}, If[m==12, {y+1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0}, {y, m+1, 1, 0, 0, 0}], "Second"]]
```

`AbsoluteTiming [secondOfYear /@ RandomDates[1000]]` takes 6 seconds.

There must be a faster easier way of doing this! I'll accept the first answer that  takes under a second for 100,000 elements.

Comment: Why don't you use a Java date difference program and [Leonid's Java compilation setup](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/7126/57)?

Comment: Nice idea! I'll look into that.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries Apparently, `AbsoluteTime` is compilable, and when you `Map` it onto a large list of dates, it is still very fast (`Map` auto-compiles). Java solution is only about 1.5 times faster, and first few times perhaps even slower (due the Java HotSpot JIT warm-up most likely). I can post it for didactic purposes, but I'd go with `AbsoluteTime`.

Comment: I'd like to see your java solution.

Comment: Ok, you got it. Note that you have to ping the person you address the comment to, like e.g. @Leonid, or that person does not get notified - I discovered your comment by chance.

Comment: Date and time functions are typically the bottlenecks in many financial related calculations. This has been a source of frustration for a long time. On the wolfram blog post for the financial platform McLoone indicated they were working on it (http://blog.wolfram.com/2012/05/15/announcing-wolfram-finance-platform/#comments).

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch Well, then, until those goodies arrive, sometimes Java can help.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin yes definitely. I was going to add that to the comment but figured it was obvious from other comments and answers :) Also in some date and time calculations you can write fast functions in Mma if you are able to sacrifice say ~0.1% accuracy -- it depends on the problem at hand.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ok, Java solution, by popular demand.

#### Solution

1. Load the [Java reloader](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6144/looking-for-longest-common-substring-solution/6376#6376)
2. Compile this class:

   ```
   JCompileLoad@
     "import java.util.Calendar;

      public class SecondOfYearVectorized{  
        public static double[] secondOfYear(int[][] dates){
           Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
           double[] result = new double[dates.length];
           for(int i=0;i<dates.length;i++){    
               calendar.set(dates[i][0],dates[i][1]-1,dates[i][2],
                     dates[i][3], dates[i][4],dates[i][5]);
               long time = (long) (calendar.getTimeInMillis()/1000);
               calendar.set(dates[i][0]-1,11,31,24,0,0);
               long timepy = (long) (calendar.getTimeInMillis()/1000);
               calendar.set(dates[i][0],11,31,24,0,0);
               long timey = (long) (calendar.getTimeInMillis()/1000);
               result[i]= ((double)(timepy-time))/(timepy-timey);
           }   
           return result;      
       }
   }"
   ```

#### Usage and comparisons

```
dates = RandomDates[100000];

SecondOfYearVectorized`secondOfYear[dates]//Short//AbsoluteTiming
```

> ```
>   {0.2460938,{0.310529,0.0296395,<<99996>>,0.0393697,0.0470913}}
> ```

```
N[secondOfYear2 /@ dates]//Short//AbsoluteTiming
```

> ```
>   {1.5937500,{0.310643,0.0296395,<<99996>>,0.0393697,0.0470913}}
> ```

#### Remarks

The Java solution seems about 6 times faster than Brett's one, and about 4 times faster than the fastest vectorized solution I could cook up with `AbsoluteTime`. The `AbsoluteTime` itself is pretty fast though, so I don't know to what should I attribute the speed-up (my guess is that I save on data transfer, which causes a performance hit, since I only transfer data once. And probably Java Calendar-based functionality is still faster by itself). Note that results obtained with Java and Mathematica solution are only approximately the same, but the differences are quite small, when any. Note also that Java solution reaches full speed after several runs, likely due to a warm-up of JVM HotSpot JIT compiler.

Answer (score 5):

You could use `AbsoluteTime` to convert to seconds:

```
In[5]:= secondOfYear2[{y_, m_, d_, h_, n_, s_}] := 
  (AbsoluteTime[{y - 1, 12, 31, 24, 0, 0}] - AbsoluteTime[{y, m, d, h, n, s}])/
    (AbsoluteTime[{y - 1, 12, 31, 24, 0, 0}] - AbsoluteTime[{y, 12, 31, 24, 0, 0}])

In[6]:= secondOfMonth2[{y_, m_, d_, h_, n_, s_}] := 
  (AbsoluteTime[{y, m, 1, 0, 0, 0}] - AbsoluteTime[{y, m, d, h, n, s}])/
      (AbsoluteTime[{y, m, 1, 0, 0, 0}] - AbsoluteTime[
          If[m == 12, {y + 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0}, {y, m + 1, 1, 0, 0, 0}]])

In[7]:= dates = RandomDates[1000];

In[8]:= AbsoluteTiming[First[secondOfYear /@ dates]]

Out[8]= {6.632562, 1973999/7884000}

In[9]:= AbsoluteTiming[First[secondOfYear2 /@ dates]]

Out[9]= {0.135024, 1973999/7884000}
```

Comment: Still slow for 100,000 elements

Comment: @Mike Of course, but not because of `AbsoluteTime` - because you set up your function so that `Map`, for example, can not auto-compile. Vectorize your problem and you will win big.

Comment: @Mike Actually, I take my words back: I tested and vectorization only speeds things up about 1.5 times, with respect to Brett's function `secondOfYear2`. So, it looks like this is more or less as fast as it gets, unless you implement some specialized version of `AbsoluteTime`, which may be faster.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin I'm down to ~2s on my machine for `secondOfMonth`, but it's boring code you'd write in CS101 without any date library functions (does look-ups for how many seconds in each month, accounting for leap years, etc...)

Comment: @BrettChampion Yeah, right ... I guess that's what libraries are for :). There are lots of more interesting problems to solve, and this stuff was probably beaten to death in any language we can name.

Answer (score 3):

Another alternative :

```
LeapYearQ[year_] := (Mod[year, 4] == 0 && Mod[year, 100] != 0) || Mod[year,400] == 0

DaysInMonth[date_] := {{1, 31}, {2, If[LeapYearQ[date[[1]]], 29, 28]}, {3, 31}, {4, 30}, {5, 31}, {6, 30}, {7, 31}, {8, 31}, {9, 30}, {10, 31}, {11, 30}, {12, 31}}[[date[[2]], 2]];

 mySOfY[{y_, m_, d_, h_, n_, s_}] := Module[{num, den},
  num = (Total[DaysInMonth[{y, #, d, h, n, s}] &  /@ Range[1, m - 1]] +
  (d - 1)) 86400 + h 3600 + n 60 + s;
  den = (Total[DaysInMonth[{y, #, d, h, n, s}] &  /@ Range[1, 12]]) 86400;
  num/den]

alist = RandomDates[1000];

{elapsedMike, mike} = secondOfYear /@ alist // AbsoluteTiming;
{elapsedFr, Fr} = mySOfY /@ alist // AbsoluteTiming;

elapsedMike
elapsedFr

(* 4.085852 *)
(* 0.136444 *)

mike === Fr

(* True *)
```

Compiled version :

```
cLeapYear = Compile[{{year, _Integer}}, (Mod[year, 4] == 0 && 
 Mod[year, 100] != 0) || Mod[year, 400] == 0, CompilationTarget -> "C"]

denF[year_] := If[cLeapYear[year], 366 86400, 365 86400]

cmySOfY = Compile[{{date, _Integer, 1}},
 Module[{num, den, y, m, d, h, n, s},
   y = date[[1]]; m = date[[2]]; d = date[[3]]; h = date[[4]]; 
   n = date[[5]]; s = date[[6]];
   num = (Total[
     DaysInMonth[{y, #, d, h, n, s}] &  /@ 
      Range[1, m - 1]] + (d - 1)) 86400 + h 3600 + n 60 + s;
  den = denF[y];
  num/den], 
   {{cLeapYear[_], True | False}, {DaysInMonth[_], _Integer}, 
    {denF[_], _Integer}}, 
   CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}, 
   RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"]
```

Still not fast enough :

```
{elapsedcFr, cFr} = cmySOfY[RandomDates[10^5]] // AbsoluteTiming;
elapsedcFr
(* 3.565060 *)
```

Comment: Still slow for 100,000 elements

Comment: @Mike Added a compiled version but it still takes 3.5 sec.