# Count items in a list that occur before a date

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list of dates that happen throughout 2013. I wish to construct a graph showing a cumulative total of elements that happen before that date.

I have a working algorithm, but it seems too slow and inefficient.

Let's generate some random dates:

```
dates = {2013, #[[1]], #[[2]]} & /@ Transpose@{RandomInteger[{1, 12}, {100}], 
    RandomInteger[{1, 30}, {100}]};
```

Define a function that calculates the totals:

```
datecounts[dates_, effectivedate_, spanindays_] := Module[{range, compares},
  range = DateRange[effectivedate, DatePlus[effectivedate, spanindays]];
  compares = Partition[(AbsoluteTime[#[[1]]] > AbsoluteTime[#[[2]]]) & /@ 
     Tuples[{range, dates}], Length[dates]];
  Transpose@{range, Count[#, True] & /@ compares}]
```

And graph the results:

```
DateListPlot[datecounts[dates, {2013, 1, 1}, 365], PlotStyle -> {Thickness[0.003]},
   Joined -> True, GridLines -> Automatic, FrameLabel -> {Null, "Total Count"}]
```

Any help in improving efficiency or better use of functions is greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Do you really need to plot every day's value? You could try `InterpolationOrder -> 0` to get your nice flat lines.

Comment: @Verbeia Great point. I'll delete that update.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
newdata =  Transpose[{dates[[Ordering[AbsoluteTime /@ dates]]], Range@Length@dates}];
DateListPlot[newdata, Joined -> True]
```

[image]

```
 DateListPlot[newdata,Joined -> True, InterpolationOrder -> 0]
```

[image]

**Update:** Let `HistogramList` do the counting:

```
 dts = AbsoluteTime /@ dates;
 (* number of says between the earliest and latest dates - 
   to be used as the number of bins in the second argument of HistogramList*)
 daysbetween = DateDifference[Sequence @@ Through[{Min, Max}[dts]]];
 DateListPlot[Transpose[Delete[
     HistogramList[dts, daysbetween, "CumulativeCount"],
     {1, 1}]],
 Joined -> True, ImageSize -> 500]
```

[image]

**Update 2:** ... there is also `EmpiricalDistribution`

```
  {min, max} = Through[{Min, Max}[dts]]; 
  Plot[CDF[EmpiricalDistribution[dts], x], {x, min, max}]
```

Comment: You get my +1 for `HistogramList`.

Answer (score 6):

Since you are just looking for counts, I would do the following:

```
DateListPlot[
 Transpose[{
   AbsoluteTime /@ Sort[#, AbsoluteTime[#1] < AbsoluteTime[#2]& ]& @ dates,
   Range @ Length @ dates
   }],
 PlotStyle -> {Thickness[0.003]}, Joined -> True, 
 GridLines -> Automatic, FrameLabel -> {Null, "Total Count"}, 
 InterpolationOrder -> 0
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Much faster, but only plots 100 points in this case instead of a point for each day in 2013... Not a bad thing, just haven't thought of it that way.

Answer (score 0):

You could use that:

```
plotDates[dates_,dtIni_,years_:1]:=Module[{newDate},
    newDate=Tally[Sort@dates];
    newDate[[All,2]]=Accumulate[newDate[[All,2]]];
    DateListPlot[newDate,Joined->True,PlotStyle->{Thick,Red},InterpolationOrder->0,PlotRange->{{dtIni,DatePlus[dtIni,{years,"Year"}]},All}]
]
```

I like this ways to accumulate the informations, it's very fast!

The result is something like your have already done.

```
plotDates[dates,{2013,1,1}]
```

[image: accumulated plot]

If you need the zeros (I regularly need to calculate come averages!), there is a answer that can helps you of a function that I called [fillDateGaps](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/11746/simpler-way-to-fill-date-gaps-with-zero-values).