# How to make Joined skip missing data points?

Tags: plotting

I have a set of data taken on sequential days, but some points are missing. I'd like to make a joined date list plot, where the points are not joined across the missing point.The following example illustrates the desired result.

```
data1 = {
{{2013, 7, 1}, 1},
{{2013, 7, 2}, 5},
{{2013, 7, 3}, 2},
{{2013, 7, 4}, 4},
{{2013, 7, 6}, 2},
{{2013, 7, 7}, 6}
};
data2 = {
{{2013, 7, 1}, 6},
{{2013, 7, 2}, 2},
{{2013, 7, 3}, 4},
{{2013, 7, 4}, 1},
{{2013, 7, 5}, 7},
{{2013, 7, 6}, 1},
{{2013, 7, 7}, 4}
};
DateListPlot[{
data1[[1 ;; 4]],
data1[[5 ;; 6]],
data2[[ ;; ]]
}, PlotStyle -> {Blue, Blue, Red}, Joined -> True]
```

Note that `data1` is missing a point on July 5. In practice I'm doing this with multiple data sets, with hundreds of points, so breaking it apart and manually assiging plotstyle like I have here is not viable.

How can I make `Joined` skip missing points?

Comment: You can insert `Indeterminate` where you don't have a date and `Joined` will skip it

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can do this pretty cleanly with `TemporalData`. Setting the `Method` to `None` ensures no interpolation will be performed. The "Part" property resamples the paths when necessary using the `Method` setting. Since it was set to `None` it gives missing at days not present in the data.

```
td = TemporalData[{data1, data2}, Method -> None];
resample = td["Part", All, {Automatic, Automatic, "Day"}]["Paths"]

DateListPlot[resample, Joined -> True, PlotStyle -> {Blue, Red}]
```

[image]

Comment: +1 Only works in version 9, though...

Comment: Cool!  I figured there was a way to do this with `TemporalData`, but hadn't looked into it yet (ie. emailed you.)

Comment: Andy, do you have any thoughts on how memory efficient (packing wise) and computationally efficient these `TemporalData` objects might be? I have data that (on the lower end) runs at about 1 sample/sec for 1 year. I currently custom slice-n-dice functions and workarounds for missing/corrupt data, etc. Everything is in terms of packed functions to keep memory and execution time small. I haven't had the chance to test TemporalData for my needs, since this project is well past it, but before I take the plunge the next time, I wanted to ask you if you had any thoughts on this.

Comment: @rm-rf They use packed arrays when possible for values and store times as {tmin, tmax, dt} (again when possible) rather than an explicit list of times.  This is actually a very general and quite powerful object but it is a bit prickly (in M9) and takes some getting used to.

Answer (score 7):

This is related to [Simpler way to fill date gaps with zero values](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/11746/121).
Combined with R.M's tip regarding `Indeterminate` we could use:

```
fillDates[dates_, val_:0] :=
  {#, Replace[#, Dispatch@Append[Rule @@@ dates, _ -> val], {1}]}\[Transpose] & @
    Part[DateList /@ Range[##, 24*60^2] & @@ AbsoluteTime /@ dates[[{1, -1}, 1]], All, ;; 3]

DateListPlot[
  fillDates[#, Indeterminate] & /@ {data1, data2},
  PlotStyle -> {Blue, Red},
  Joined -> True
]
```

[image]

Comment: Instead of `Indeterminate` you could also use `Missing[]`.

Comment: @Jens It seems we can use `Null` or `""` as well!  Can you confirm?

Comment: Yes, anything that's undefined - but I thought `Missing` is more appropriate here and may actually make the result of `fillDates` more usable for other purposes...

Answer (score 5):

Why not just write a function to split up the data for you and then plot it.

**edit:** now with automated `PlotStyle` coloring

```
splitdata[data_] := 
 Split[data, DateDifference[#1[[1]], #2[[1]]] == 1 &]

split = splitdata /@ {data1, data2};
lengths = Length /@ split;
colors = {Blue, Red, Green, Purple};
DateListPlot[Join @@ split, Joined -> True, 
 PlotStyle -> 
  Flatten@MapThread[
    ConstantArray, {Take[colors, Length@lengths], lengths}]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
a =
  {{{2013, 7, 1}, 1}, {{2013, 7, 2}, 5}, {{2013, 7, 3}, 2}, {{2013, 7, 4}, 4}, {{2013, 7, 6}, 2}, {{2013, 7, 7}, 6}};

b =
  {{{2013, 7, 1}, 6}, {{2013, 7, 2}, 2}, {{2013, 7, 3}, 4}, {{2013, 7, 4}, 1}, {{2013, 7, 5}, 7}, {{2013, 7, 6}, 1}, {{2013, 7, 7}, 4}};
```

`KeyUnion` automatically replaces missing values with `Missing[]`:

```
KeyUnion[{<|Rule @@@ a|>, <|Rule @@@ b|>}] // DateListPlot
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

#### [TimeSeriesResample](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TimeSeriesResample.html) + [ResamplingMethod](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ResamplingMethod.html)

```
ts = TimeSeriesResample[{data1, data2}, "Union", ResamplingMethod -> None];


DateListPlot[ts, PlotStyle -> {Blue, Red}]
```

[image]