# Aligning two lists

Tags: list-manipulation

I have two lists, L1 and L2, each with a key and some data. Let us say the key is a person's name, a string, and the data follows. (To respond to *rasher*'s query:) Let us also assume the lists are sorted
by key:

```
L1 = {
       {"Joseph O'Rourke", data1, data2, ... },
       ...
     }
```

I would like to "align" the two lists in the following sense.
If L1 has a name A that is not in L2, then L2 is padded to include a "blank" record for A. And vice versa: If L2 has a name B that is not in L1, then L1 is modified to include a "blank" record for B. Then I will have two lists that "align":

```
L1' = { {A,...}, {0,...}, {C,...},  {D,...}, ...}
L2' = { {A,...}, {B,...}, {0,...},  {D,...}, ...}
```

where maybe `0 == {}`. With the lists aligned in this fashion,
I could make a two-column table (one column per list) that would directly compare one
list against the other. My question is:

> What is a clean method for accepting L1 and L2 as input, and returning L1' and L2' as output, with the latter two lists aligned as above?

I can accomplish this via tedious list For-loops, but I suspect the cognoscenti :-)
will offer more concise and efficient methods. Thanks for your help!

Comment: something like `SequenceAlignment["ABCDEG", "ABDEFG"]`?

Comment: Are the lists already sorted by key, and if not, if the results are sorted by key is that acceptable?

Comment: @rasher: Yes, let's assume the lists are already sorted by key.

Comment: @belisarius: Yes! I was ignorant of `SequenceAlignment[]`.

Comment: Related: [(11746)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/11746), [(29164)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/29164)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm late to the party but I like this kind of problem so I'm going to answer anyway.

I propose this:

```
f1[a_List, b_List, fill_: {0, {}}] :=
  With[{all = a ⋃ b},
    Replace[
      Join[all, #] ~GatherBy~ First,
      {{_} -> fill, {__, x_} :> x},
      1
    ] & /@ {a, b}
  ]
```

Test:

```
a = {{1, 7}, {3, 7}, {5, 2}, {8, 7}};
b = {{3, 1}, {6, 6}, {8, 7}, {9, 3}};

f1[a, b] // Grid
```

$
\begin{array}{cccccc}
 \{1,7\} & \{3,7\} & \{5,2\} & \{0,\{\}\} & \{8,7\} & \{0,\{\}\} \\
 \{0,\{\}\} & \{3,1\} & \{0,\{\}\} & \{6,6\} & \{8,7\} & \{9,3\}
\end{array}
$

Note that this sample includes keys with both identical (`{8, 7}`) and divergent (`{3, 7}`, `{3, 1}`) data.

Comment: +1, clean and pretty fast. And just elegant, as always.

Comment: Nice! Could you (or someone) please explain `~GatherBy~`, especially the tildas. Thanks!

Comment: @JosephO'Rourke `x ~ f ~ y` is equivalent to `f[x,y]`. It's called "Infix notation"

Comment: @rasher Thanks.  Since you like (at least some aspect of) my style, would you mind me refactoring the code in your answer to reduce duplication?  Not only would that make it shorter, but IMO it would be clearer too, as the differences from one line to the next would be directly apparent as arguments.

Comment: @Joseph Yes, it's infix notation, and I've been confusing people with it since at least 2011. :o)  I find nested brackets very hard to read and I often use infix notation to reduce their use.  I also like way that code reads left-to-right when binary operations are strung together.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: Feel free - honestly, consider this as carte blanche forward to prettify any of my stuff... I seldom aim for beauty here. PS - might want to test `Union` vs the `DeleteDuplicates` for the complement - did not re-test for speed, but one may be better than other (and vice versa) depending on key structure...

Comment: Could someone explain the pattern line, `{{_} -> fill, {__, x_} :> x},` ?

Comment: @Joseph After gathering the elements: a list with a single occurrence, which is matched by the pattern `{_}`, represents a missing key in the list under operation and needs to be replaced with the `fill` expression (provided as an optional argument with a default value).  A list with multiple occurrences, matched by the pattern `{__, x_}`, represents a present key, and we want the last element gathered (matched by `x_`) because it came from the list under operation.  If this is still not clear, or you are having trouble understanding the patterns themselves, let me know and I'll try again.

Comment: Thank you, that is quite clear!

Answer (score 7):

If the lists are long (several hundred or more), `Alternatives` will get to be slow.  Here's another way that will be faster on longer lists:

```
align[list1_, list2_] := Module[{base, replace1, replace2},
  base = Union[First /@ list1, First /@ list2];
  With[{arg = First[#]}, replace1[arg] = #] & /@ list1;
  replace1[_] = {0, {}};
  With[{arg = First[#]}, replace2[arg] = #] & /@ list2;
  replace2[_] = {0, {}};
  {replace1 /@ base, replace2 /@ base}
```

Example:

```
data = {"that", "natural", "cowards", "delay", "country", "himself", 
   "my", "will", "cast", "office", "native", "is", "awry", "s", "ay"};

l1 = {#, ToCharacterCode[#]} & /@ Sort@RandomSample[data, 10]
l2 = {#, {StringLength[#]}} & /@ Sort@RandomSample[data, 10]
(*
  {{"ay", {97, 121}}, {"cast", {99, 97, 115, 116}},
   {"cowards", {99, 111, 119, 97, 114, 100, 115}}, {"delay", {100, 101, 108, 97, 121}},
   {"himself", {104, 105, 109, 115, 101, 108, 102}}, {"is", {105, 115}},
   {"my", {109, 121}}, {"native", {110, 97, 116, 105, 118, 101}},
   {"that", {116, 104, 97, 116}}, {"will", {119, 105, 108, 108}}}

  {{"cast", {4}}, {"cowards", {7}}, {"delay", {5}}, {"is", {2}}, {"my", {2}},
   {"native", {6}},{"natural", {7}}, {"s", {1}}, {"that", {4}}, {"will", {4}}} 
*)

align[l1, l2];
Grid[Transpose@{newl1, newl2}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: +1, and we both over-thought it (within apparent constraints of data in OP) - see my update.

Answer (score 2):

### TemporalData + ResamplingMethod

```
ClearAll[timeAlign]
timeAlign = Module[{td = TemporalData[{##}, ResamplingMethod -> {"Constant", {}}], times},
  times = Union @@ td["TimeList"];
  Thread[{times, #}] & /@ Through @ td["PathFunctions"] @ times]&;
```

**Example:** using Mr.Wizard's example lists

```
a = {{1, 7}, {3, 7}, {5, 2}, {8, 7}};
b = {{3, 1}, {6, 6}, {8, 7}, {9, 3}};

timeAlign[a, b]
```

> {{{1, 7}, {3, 7}, {5, 2}, {6, {}}, {8, 7}, {9, {}}},
> {{1, {}}, {3, 1}, {5, {}}, {6, 6}, {8, 7}, {9, 3}}}

### Association + KeyUnion

```
KeyValueMap[List]/@KeyUnion[Association/@(Rule @@@ # & /@ {a, b})]/. _Missing -> {}
```

> {{{1, 7}, {3, 7}, {5, 2}, {8, 7}, {6, {}}, {9, {}}},
> {{1, {}}, {3, 1}, {5, {}}, {8,7}, {6, 6}, {9, 3}}}