# DatePlus and DayPlus perform much worse than my user-defined-function

Tags: performance-tuning, date-and-time

I was debugging a function speed, and discovered that the time bottleneck was in `DatePlus`. I tried to change to `DayPlus` and get a even worse result.

Here are my time tests:

```
myDatePlus = DateList[AbsoluteTime[#1] + 86400*#2][[ ;; 3]] &;
n = 10^4;
t1 = (Table[myDatePlus[{2015, 3, 100}, 365], {i, 0, n}]; // 
        AbsoluteTiming // First)
t2 = (Table[DatePlus[{2015, 3, 100}, 365], {i, 0, n}]; // 
        AbsoluteTiming // First)
t3 = (Table[Normal[DayPlus[{2015, 3, 100}, 365]][[ ;; 3]], {i, 0, n}]; //
        AbsoluteTiming // First)

N[t2/t1]
N[t3/t1]
```

> ```
> >   0.068  (*t1*)
> >   3.957  (*t2*)
> >  13.428  (*t3*)
>
> >  58.19   (*t2/t1*)
> > 197.47   (*t3/t1*)
> ```

Can someone confirm it? Is `t1` the best way to do it in current *Mathematica* version? (V10.0.2)

Comment: Many of the built-in date functions are very slow. For bulk data I usually use my own functions.

Comment: Have you seen some of the past questions / answers on this topic, involving Java, like [this discussion](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/7246/faster-alternatives-to-datedifference) for instance? I found that for date functions, and when you need to perform operations in a bulk, this approach works well.

Comment: I used to send comparative benchmarks to Wolfram with every Mathematica release, pointing out how slow their date functions were compared to other interpreted languages. They don't seem to view this as a priority, but perhaps if more of us were to complain they would tackle the problem.

Answer (score 4):

This question deserves an answer and even better, the answer is also good news as much has improved by now.

```
$Version
(* 14.0.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (December 13, 2023) *)

With[
  {
    myDatePlus = DateList[ AbsoluteTime[#1] + 86400. * #2 ]&,
    n = 10^4
  },
  Module[
    {t1,t2,t3, performance},
    t1 := Inactivate @ Table[ myDatePlus[ {2024, 2, 7}, 365 ], {i, n}];
    t2 := Inactivate @ Table[ DatePlus[ {2024, 2, 7}, 365 ], {i,n} ];
    t3 := Inactivate @ Table[ DayPlus[ {2024, 2, 7}, 365 ], {i, n} ];
    performance = Map[ Activate /* AbsoluteTiming /* First, { t1, t2, t3 } ];
    performance // Association[
      "AbsoluteTime" -> #[[1]],
      "DatePlus" -> #[[2]],
      "DayPlus" -> #[[3]],
      "DatePlus : AbsoluteTime" -> #[[2]]/#[[1]],
      "DayPlus : AbsoluteTime" -> #[[3]]/#[[1]]
    ]& // Dataset
  ]
]
```

[image: Dataset Output]

The main culprit for the slower performance of the `DayPlus` function seems to be `DateObject` and its overhead being used. The `DatePlus` function allows for much more flexibility.

If we replace `{2024, 2, 7}` with `Today` as to start with `DateObject` as input for all three functions, it is nice to note that `DatePlus` remains very fast.

**Result using `Today` as input**

[image]

**Remarks**

1. I did not bother to use `[[ ;; 3]]` as to "crop" the `DateList` format to `{ y, m, d }` as this will not change the result significantly.
2. Note, that `Normal` has been modified since `v10.0.2` and—as of `v14`—will now not give a `DateList` when applied to a `DateObject`. Instead, one would need to apply `DateList` itself, e.g., `DateList[ DateObject[...] ]`.

Comment: @Murta You deserved an answer; you got one. ;-)