# Does Mathematica support importing ISO 8601 date strings?

Tags: import, date-and-time

Does *Mathematica* have a built-in function to convert [ISO 8601 formatted](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) date strings (e.g. `2012-01-04T00:00:00`) to a date list?

ISO 8601 strings come in a variety of formats:

```
Date alone: 2012-12-03
Combined date and time: 2012-12-03T22:02
Combined date and time with time zone: 2012-12-03T22:02:47.23+01
```

On top of that individual components can be omitted (see the Wiki page). I am looking for a solution that covers the whole ISO 8601 standard.

Comment: Unfortunately I think you need to roll your own in that case.

Comment: Whhooaaa, I'm just realizing you are *the* sakra! The one who was so kind to implement a `findMathematica` for cmake ;-) You cannot imagine how easy life is with your tool.

Comment: A July 2015 blog post says the Wolfram Language is finally [getting native ISO 8601 support](http://blog.wolfram.com/2015/07/09/new-in-the-wolfram-language-iso-dates-and-more/).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `JLink` (as already mentioned while I read JavaDoc). Searching StackOverflow brings up this highly voted answer

[Converting ISO8601-compliant String to java.util.Date](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2202300/1078614)

I don't know whether it covers the whole standard but this works out of the box. If this is not sufficient, you can use an equivalent piece of code written for [Joda Time](http://johannburkard.de/blog/programming/java/date-time-parsing-formatting-joda-time.html)

```
Needs["JLink`"]

ParseDateString[date_String] := JavaBlock[
  InstallJava[];
  LoadJavaClass["javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter", 
   StaticsVisible -> True];
  DateList[
   javax`xml`bind`DatatypeConverter`parseDateTime[date]@getTime[]@toString[]
  ]
]
```

This uses the `DataypeConverter` class which is available without in standard Java 6. It converts it into a standard date string which can then be used with `DateList`.

```
ParseDateString["2010-01-01T12:00:00Z"]

(* {2010, 1, 1, 13, 0, 0.} *)
```

Comment: Does this cover the whole ISO 8601 standard? The o/p wrote: "I am looking for a solution that covers the whole ISO 8601 standard."

Comment: Probably not, but I want a working example here. To put another jar in the classpath and write your own method is easy from this point IMO.

Answer (score 4):

As of *Mathematica* 10.2, [DateString](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DateString.html) and [DateObject](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DateObject.html) support this format directly. For example:

```
In[1]:= DateObject["2015-09-17T03:12:44"]
Out[1]= DateObject[{2015, 9, 17}, TimeObject[{3, 12, 44.}, TimeZone -> -4.],
         TimeZone -> -4.]
```

Comment: fails with Time Zone offset, eg "2022-04-18T14:02:10.326+0000" // DateObject and "2022-04-18T14:02:10.326+00:00" // DateObject,- both are valid [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)

Answer (score 3):

The best option as of version 12.2 is [FromISOTimstamp](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/FromISOTimestamp/) from the Wolfram Function Repository.

Answer (score 2):

Use Joda Time with JLink. Joda is fully 8601-compliant, and with JLink the whole Java universe is immediately at your fingertips from M.

I've posted a few replies in this forum using Joda Time, for example
[Faster alternatives for DayOfWeek](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/7125/faster-alternatives-for-dayofweek/7954#7954)

where I've mentioned that Joda Time is fully 8601-compliant.

Answer (score 1):

I want to build upon @halirutan answer.

The reason why I need to build upon the answer is DatatypeConverter`parseDateTime actually returns in the following format "**Mon Mar 10 21:24:10 GMT+08:00 2014**", and DateList[] can't automatically interpret the returned date

Hence, I need to provide the explicit format to DateList[] to make it work in Mathematica. The explicit format is "**{"DayName"," ","MonthName"," ","Day"," ", "Hour",":","Minute",":","Second"," GMT+08:00 ", "Year"}**"

Please take note of the Time Zone portion. My time zone is GMT+08:00, hence I hard coded it in the explicit format. Most likely you need to update to your own time zone for it to work successfully. For example, your time zone is GMT-08:00 if you are in USA West Coast.

```
Needs["JLink`"]

ParseDateString[date_String] := JavaBlock[
  InstallJava[];
  LoadJavaClass["javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter", 
   StaticsVisible -> True];
  DateList[{
   javax`xml`bind`DatatypeConverter`parseDateTime[date]@getTime[]@toString[],
   {"DayName", " ", "MonthName", " ", "Day", " ", "Hour", ":", "Minute",":", "Second", " GMT+08:00 ", "Year"}}
  ]
]

ParseDateString["2014-03-10T09:24:10.000-04:00"]
```

And the result will be

```
{2014, 3, 10, 21, 24, 10.}
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like `AbsoluteTime` might get you close.  My examples here don't include the final `04:00`.

```
In[1]:= AbsoluteTime["2014-07-31T10:19:08.985"]
Out[1]= 3.615790748985000*10^9

In[2]:= ToExpression /@ 
 StringSplit["2014-07-31T10:19:08.985", ("-" | "T" | ":")]
Out[2]= {2014, 7, 31, 10, 19, 8.985}

In[3]:= AbsoluteTime@%
Out[3]= 3.615790748985000*10^9
```