# Test whether date is in a certain period

Tags: list-manipulation, date-and-time

I have one table which contains time periods (`"start"` and `"end"`) and a `"type"` for every period:

```
table1 = {{"start", "end", "type"}, 
          {{2013, 8, 10, 8, 5, 0.`}, {2013, 8, 10, 10, 6, 0.`}, "a"}, 
          {{2013, 8, 10, 10, 6, 0.`}, {2013, 8, 10, 10, 50, 0.`}, "b"}, 
          {{2013, 8, 10, 10, 50, 0.`}, {2013, 8, 10, 12, 10, 10.`}, "c"}}
```

Now, I have a second table which contains dates:

```
table2 = {"date", 
          {2013, 8, 10, 11, 5, 0.`}, 
          {2013, 8, 10, 10, 15, 0.`}, 
          {2013, 8, 10, 10, 35, 0.`},
          {2013, 8, 10, 11, 10, 0.`}, 
          {2013, 8, 10, 12, 5, 0.`}}
```

What I want to do now, is to test whether a date is within one of the periods and if yes in which period. The result should be a table which shows in which period the date is. For my small example, the table should look like this:

```
result = {{"date", "coresp. type"}, 
          {{2013, 8, 10, 11, 5, 0.`}, "c"}, 
          {{2013, 8, 10, 10, 15, 0.`}, "b"}, 
          {{2013, 8, 10, 8, 5, 0.`}, "a"}, 
          {{2013, 8, 10, 11, 10, 0.`}, "c"}, 
          {{2013, 8, 10, 12, 5, 0.`}, "c"}, 
          {{2013, 9, 10, 10, 10, 0.`}, "none"}}
```

Is there an way to create the result table automatically?

Comment: Ah, I deleted my answer but now I know whats wrong. Your `result` does not fit `table2`...

Comment: You are right I did copy the false version of table2, sorry for that.

Comment: Frink, I humbly ask that you review the comparative timing that I have added to my answer and reconsider your selection.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would do it like this, using [`AbsoluteTime`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/AbsoluteTime.html), which is often [much faster](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/7252/121) than alternatives.

```
Module[{
  intv = Interval /@ Map[AbsoluteTime, table1[[2 ;;, {1, 2}]], {-2}],
  type = table1[[2 ;;, 3]],
  data = Rest[table2],
  out
 },
 out = Pick[type, intv ~IntervalMemberQ~ #] & /@ AbsoluteTime /@ data;
 Join[List /@ data, out /. {} -> {"none"}, 2] ~Prepend~ {"date", "coresp. type"}
]
```

> ```
> {{"date", "coresp. type"},
>  {{2013, 8, 10, 11, 5, 0.`}, "c"},
>  {{2013, 8, 10, 10, 15, 0.`}, "b"},
>  {{2013, 8, 10, 10, 35, 0.`}, "b"},
>  {{2013, 8, 10, 11, 10, 0.`}, "c"},
>  {{2013, 8, 10, 12, 5, 0.`}, "c"}}
> ```

---

### Comparative Timings

With apologies to Kuba, since I feel that the method that was Accepted is vastly inferior to this one I am compelled to provide support for my position.

I will generate a large set of sample data.  I will leave out the header rows in all data for simplicity.

```
t1big =
  Join[
    Partition[DateList /@ Range[1.43*^9, 3*^9, 3*^7], 2, 1],
    List /@ CharacterRange["A", "z"] ~Drop~ {27, 32},
    2
  ];

t2big = RandomSample[DateList /@ Range[1*^9, 3*^9, 1*^6]];

Length /@ {t1big, t2big}
```

> ```
> {52, 2001}
> ```

The timing function:

```
timeAvg = 
  Function[func,
    Do[If[# > 0.3, Return[#/5^i]] & @@ Timing@Do[func, {5^i}], {i, 0, 15}],
    HoldFirst];
```

First Kuba's method:

```
With[{
   table1 = t1big,
   table2 = t2big
  },
  new = {};
  len = Length@table1;
  Do[
     If[i == len + 1, AppendTo[new, {#, "None"}]; Break[];];
     If[DateDifference[#, table1[[i, 2]]] >= 0 && DateDifference[table1[[i, 1]], #] >= 0, 
      AppendTo[new, {#, table1[[i, 3]]}]; Break[]],
     {i, 1, len + 1}
  ] & /@ table2;
  new
] // timeAvg
```

> 80.2

Then mine:

```
Module[{
   intv = Interval /@ Map[AbsoluteTime, t1big[[All, {1, 2}]], {-2}],
   type = t1big[[All, 3]],
   data = t2big,
   out
  },
  out = Pick[type, intv ~IntervalMemberQ~ #] & /@ AbsoluteTime /@ data;
  Join[List /@ data, out /. {} -> {"none"}, 2]
] // timeAvg
```

> 0.03304

So my method is **~2400X faster than Kuba's.**

Comment: Another neat use of Pick...I have to use this more.

Comment: I cannot get the code to run without removing Module, i.e. making separate expressions. The "none" case is not listed but not labelled: a minor point. My answer uses the same principle of mapping dates to real numbers, though my function is poor it is effective. The "none" case can bet tested either from the second dataset in the answer or from my answer (res). However, I have stripped the header.

Comment: @ubpdqn Sorry, minor transcription error.  Fixed now.

Comment: Thanks @Mr.Wizard : works now. Meant to write "none" case is listed but not labelled, but this is a minor point. I am learning a lot studying your coding practice.

Comment: @ubpdqn You're right, I forgot `"none"`, and I was too busy yesterday to fix it; I'll do that now.  I'm glad you like my code, but remember it's only one style and *Mathematica* supports many.

Comment: @ubpdqn I didn't notice that you were already using `IntervalMemberQ`.  +1 on your answer. :-)

Comment: Thank you @Mr.Wizard. That was whole point of creating my own strictly mono tonic increasing silly function. The ugly code surrounding it was largely to label the none case but even this is much more ugly than necessary. So, I learned a lot from your code.

Answer (score 4):

It can be done faster if we know more about those intervals, if they can overlap etc.

But let's make an assumption that there is only **one or none** date interval matching for each date in `table2`.

**Edit:** your `result` is for different `table2` than you showed so let's take what you've taken:

```
table2 = Rest[result][[ ;; , 1]]
```

Also, probably there is something built in but meanwhile:

```
new = {};
len = Length@table1;
Do[
   If[i == len + 1, AppendTo[new, {#, "None"}]; Break[];];
   If[DateDifference[#, table1[[i, 2]]] >= 0 && 
      DateDifference[table1[[i, 1]], #] >= 0
      ,
      AppendTo[new, {#, table1[[i, 3]]}]; Break[]], 
  {i, 1, len + 1}] & /@ table2;

new
```

> ```
> {{{2013, 8, 10, 11, 5, 0.}, "c"}, {{2013, 8, 10, 10, 15, 0.}, "b"}, 
>   {{2013, 8, 10, 8, 5, 0.}, "a"}, {{2013, 8, 10, 11, 10, 0.}, "c"}, 
>   {{2013, 8, 10, 12, 5, 0.}, "c"}, {{2013, 9, 10, 10, 10, 0.}, "None"}}
> ```

Comment: the assumption one or none is correct, did forget to mention that

Answer (score 2):

I make the assumptions, as above, of disjoint intervals and test data belongs to one or no interval.

I note that your original and result test data are not the same.
The following is not elegant and I look forward to better solutions. It does work.

```
(* Strip header *)    
tab1=Drop[table1,1];
(* Define function to map date to number *)
    df[u_] := {10000, 100, 1, 0.01, 0.0001, 0.000001}.u;
(* Use Which to categorize *)
    f[x_] := Which @@ 
       Join[Flatten[{IntervalMemberQ[#[[1]], 
             df[x]], {x, #[[2]]}} & /@ ({Interval[{df@#[[1]], 
                df@#[[2]]}], #[[3]]} & /@ tab1), 
         1], {True, {x, "none"}}];
```

Applying `f/@res` to your second test set:

```
res={{2013, 8, 10, 11, 5, 0.}, {2013, 8, 10, 10, 15, 0.}, {2013, 8, 10, 8,
   5, 0.}, {2013, 8, 10, 11, 10, 0.}, {2013, 8, 10, 12, 5, 0.}, {2013,
   9, 10, 10, 10, 0.}}
```

yields:

```
   {
{{2013, 8, 10, 11, 5, 0.},"c"},
{{2013, 8, 10, 10, 15, 0.},"b"},
{{2013, 8, 10, 8, 5, 0.},"a"},
{{2013, 8, 10, 11, 10, 0.},"c"}, 
{{2013, 8, 10, 12, 5, 0.},"c"},
{{2013, 9, 10, 10, 10, 0.},"none"}
}
```

consistent with the question.

For the original test data:

```
tab2={{2013, 8, 10, 11, 5, 0.}, {2013, 8, 10, 10, 15, 0.}, {2013, 8, 10, 
  10, 35, 0.}, {2013, 8, 10, 11, 10, 0.}, {2013, 8, 10, 12, 5, 0.}}
```

yields:

```
    {
{{2013, 8, 10, 11, 5, 0.}, "c"},
{{2013, 8, 10, 10, 15, 0.},"b"},
{{2013, 8, 10, 10, 35, 0.},"b"},
{{2013, 8, 10, 11, 10, 0.},"c"}, 
{{2013, 8, 10, 12, 5, 0.}, "c"}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just factored it differently, nothing special:

```
period[dt_, {start_, end_, period_}] := 
  If[DateDifference[start, dt ] > 0 &&   DateDifference[dt, end] > 0, 
     period];
getPeriod[dt_] := 
  First[DeleteCases[period[dt, #] & /@ Rest[table1], Null]];
Table[{date, getPeriod[date]}, {date , Rest[table2]}]

{
 {{2013, 8, 10, 11, 5, 0.}, "c"}, 
 {{2013, 8, 10, 10, 15, 0.}, "b"}, 
 {{2013, 8, 10, 10, 35, 0.}, "b"}, 
 {{2013, 8, 10, 11, 10, 0.}, "c"}, 
 {{2013, 8, 10, 12, 5, 0.}, "c"}
}
```