# how to mean of day,month value

Tags: date-and-time

data={{{2006, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0.}, 326.492, {2006, 1, 1, 3, 0, 
  0.}, 323.08, {2006, 1, 1, 6, 0, 0.}, 314.223, {2006, 1, 1, 9, 0, 
  0.}, 314.361, {2006, 1, 1, 12, 0, 0.}, 322.048, {2006, 1, 1, 15, 0, 
  0.}, 323.954, {2006, 1, 1, 18, 0, 0.}, 329.694, {2006, 1, 1, 21, 0, 
  0.}, 328.151, {2006, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0.}, 330.2, {2006, 1, 2, 3, 0, 
  0.}, 326.028, {2006, 1, 2, 6, 0, 0.}, 321.627, {2006, 1, 2, 9, 0, 
  0.}, 322.35, {2006, 1, 2, 12, 0, 0.}, 324.12, {2006, 1, 2, 15, 0, 
  0.}, 326.305, {2006, 1, 2, 18, 0, 0.}, 326.472, {2006, 1, 2, 21, 0, 
  0.}, 328.135, {2006, 1, 3, 0, 0, 0.}, 329.194, {2006, 1, 3, 3, 0, 
  0.}, 327.481, {2006, 1, 3, 6, 0, 0.}, 326.669, {2006, 1, 3, 9, 0, 
  0.}, 328.192, {2006, 1, 3, 12, 0, 0.}, 333.164, {2006, 1, 3, 15, 0, 
  0.}, 335.645, {2006, 1, 3, 18, 0, 0.}, 336.476, {2006, 1, 3, 21, 0, 
  0.}, 338.306, {2006, 1, 4, 0, 0, 0.}, 339.458, {2006, 1, 4, 3, 0, 
  0.}, 334.536, {2006, 1, 4, 6, 0, 0.}, 328.724, {2006, 1, 4, 9, 0, 
  0.}, 328.655, {2006, 1, 4, 12, 0, 0.}, 332.485, {2006, 1, 4, 15, 0, 
  0.}, 335.088, {2006, 1, 4, 18, 0, 0.}, 337.114, {2006, 1, 4, 21, 0, 
  0.}, 337.366, {2006, 1, 5, 0, 0, 0.}, 338.779, {2006, 1, 5, 3, 0, 
  0.}, 335.708, {2006, 1, 5, 6, 0, 0.}, 326.423, {2006, 1, 5, 9, 0, 
  0.}, 325.267, {2006, 1, 5, 12, 0, 0.}, 329.921, {2006, 1, 5, 15, 0, 
  0.}, 332.107, {2006, 1, 5, 18, 0, 0.}, 333.599, {2006, 1, 5, 21, 0, 
  0.}, 333.82, {2006, 1, 6, 0, 0, 0.}, 334.48, {2006, 1, 6, 3, 0, 
  0.}, 330.553, {2006, 1, 6, 6, 0, 0.}, 321.303, {2006, 1, 6, 9, 0, 
  0.}, 320.164, {2006, 1, 6, 12, 0, 0.}, 325.976, {2006, 1, 6, 15, 0, 
  0.}, 326.513, {2006, 1, 6, 18, 0, 0.}, 329.622, {2006, 1, 6, 21, 0, 
  0.}, 330.697, {2006, 1, 7, 0, 0, 0.}, 331.182, {2006, 1, 7, 3, 0, 
  0.}, 326.039, {2006, 1, 7, 6, 0, 0.}, 318.691, {2006, 1, 7, 9, 0, 
  0.}, 318.71, {2006, 1, 7, 12, 0, 0.}, 324.686, {2006, 1, 7, 15, 0, 
  0.}, 326.495, {2006, 1, 7, 18, 0, 0.}, 328.6, {2006, 1, 7, 21, 0, 
  0.}, 329.187, {2006, 1, 8, 0, 0, 0.}, 331.104, {2006, 1, 8, 3, 0, 
  0.}, 326.403, {2006, 1, 8, 6, 0, 0.}, 319.914, {2006, 1, 8, 9, 0, 
  0.}, 319.141, {2006, 1, 8, 12, 0, 0.}, 320.443, {2006, 1, 8, 15, 0, 
  0.}, 323.578, {2006, 1, 8, 18, 0, 0.}, 326.673, {2006, 1, 8, 21, 0, 
  0.}, 328.346, {2006, 1, 9, 0, 0, 0.}, 330.256, {2006, 1, 9, 3, 0, 
  0.}, 328.464, {2006, 1, 9, 6, 0, 0.}, 319.662, {2006, 1, 9, 9, 0, 
  0.}, 320.738, {2006, 1, 9, 12, 0, 0.}, 325.786, {2006, 1, 9, 15, 0, 
  0.}, 334.061, {2006, 1, 9, 18, 0, 0.}, 329.304, {2006, 1, 9, 21, 0, 
  0.}, 328.593, {2006, 1, 10, 0, 0, 0.}, 326.963, {2006, 1, 10, 3, 0, 
  0.}, 322.941, {2006, 1, 10, 6, 0, 0.}, 313.76, {2006, 1, 10, 9, 0, 
  0.}, 312.741, {2006, 1, 10, 12, 0, 0.}, 314.636, {2006, 1, 10, 15, 
  0, 0.}, 316.681, {2006, 1, 10, 18, 0, 0.}, 318.124, {2006, 1, 10, 
  21, 0, 0.}, 319.609, {2006, 1, 11, 0, 0, 0.}, 321.136, {2006, 1, 11,
   3, 0, 0.}, 319.109, {2006, 1, 11, 6, 0, 0.}, 314.94, {2006, 1, 11, 
  9, 0, 0.}, 314.124, {2006, 1, 11, 12, 0, 0.}, 314.691, {2006, 1, 11,
   15, 0, 0.}, 315.855, {2006, 1, 11, 18, 0, 0.}, 316.476, {2006, 1, 
  11, 21, 0, 0.}, 317.422, {2006, 1, 12, 0, 0, 0.}, 320.974, {2006, 1,
   12, 3, 0, 0.}, 320.894, {2006, 1, 12, 6, 0, 0.}, 317.82, {2006, 1, 
  12, 9, 0, 0.}, 320.186, {2006, 1, 12, 12, 0, 0.}, 323.888, {2006, 1,
   12, 15, 0, 0.}, 323.839, {2006, 1, 12, 18, 0, 0.}, 323.132, {2006, 
  1, 12, 21, 0, 0.}, 326.405, {2006, 1, 13, 0, 0, 0.}, 329.781, {2006,
   1, 13, 3, 0, 0.}, 326.373, {2006, 1, 13, 6, 0, 0.}, 319.098, {2006,
   1, 13, 9, 0, 0.}, 319.103, {2006, 1, 13, 12, 0, 0.}, 323.52, {2006,
   1, 13, 15, 0, 0.}, 327.681, {2006, 1, 13, 18, 0, 
  0.}, 318.762, {2006, 1, 13, 21, 0, 0.}, 319.757, {2006, 1, 14, 0, 0,
   0.}, 317.946, {2006, 1, 14, 3, 0, 0.}, 318.51, {2006, 1, 14, 6, 0, 
  0.}, 318.662, {2006, 1, 14, 9, 0, 0.}, 318.798, {2006, 1, 14, 12, 0,
   0.}, 323.251, {2006, 1, 14, 15, 0, 0.}, 327.992, {2006, 1, 14, 18, 
  0, 0.}, 336.417, {2006, 1, 14, 21, 0, 0.}, 329.91, {2006, 1, 15, 0, 
  0, 0.}, 330.959, {2006, 1, 15, 3, 0, 0.}, 325.356, {2006, 1, 15, 6, 
  0, 0.}, 320.116, {2006, 1, 15, 9, 0, 0.}, 318.204, {2006, 1, 15, 12,
   0, 0.}, 324.788, {2006, 1, 15, 15, 0, 0.}, 326.794, {2006, 1, 15, 
  18, 0, 0.}, 326.043, {2006, 1, 15, 21, 0, 0.}, 328.213, {2006, 1, 
  16, 0, 0, 0.}, 329.418, {2006, 1, 16, 3, 0, 0.}, 325.934, {2006, 1, 
  16, 6, 0, 0.}, 320.338, {2006, 1, 16, 9, 0, 0.}, 319.361, {2006, 1, 
  16, 12, 0, 0.}, 325.494, {2006, 1, 16, 15, 0, 0.}, 327.167, {2006, 
  1, 16, 18, 0, 0.}, 328.414, {2006, 1, 16, 21, 0, 
  0.}, 329.696, {2006, 1, 17, 0, 0, 0.}, 330.53, {2006, 1, 17, 3, 0, 
  0.}, 326.143, {2006, 1, 17, 6, 0, 0.}, 320.913, {2006, 1, 17, 9, 0, 
  0.}, 320.573, {2006, 1, 17, 12, 0, 0.}, 325.655, {2006, 1, 17, 15, 
  0, 0.}, 328.056, {2006, 1, 17, 18, 0, 0.}, 330.983, {2006, 1, 17, 
  21, 0, 0.}, 329.368, {2006, 1, 18, 0, 0, 0.}, 327.041, {2006, 1, 18,
   3, 0, 0.}, 324.301, {2006, 1, 18, 6, 0, 0.}, 319.651, {2006, 1, 18,
   9, 0, 0.}, 320.206, {2006, 1, 18, 12, 0, 0.}, 326.33, {2006, 1, 18,
   15, 0, 0.}, 328.402, {2006, 1, 18, 18, 0, 0.}, 333.758, {2006, 1, 
  18, 21, 0, 0.}, 330.415, {2006, 1, 19, 0, 0, 0.}, 331.269, {2006, 1,
   19, 3, 0, 0.}, 325.665, {2006, 1, 19, 6, 0, 0.}, 320.229, {2006, 1,
   19, 9, 0, 0.}, 319.886, {2006, 1, 19, 12, 0, 0.}, 325.75, {2006, 1,
   19, 15, 0, 0.}, 326.794, {2006, 1, 19, 18, 0, 0.}, 327.799, {2006, 
  1, 19, 21, 0, 0.}, 327.676, {2006, 1, 20, 0, 0, 0.}, 326.539, {2006,
   1, 20, 3, 0, 0.}, 323.767, {2006, 1, 20, 6, 0, 0.}, 321.039, {2006,
   1, 20, 9, 0, 0.}, 318.396, {2006, 1, 20, 12, 0, 
  0.}, 322.366, {2006, 1, 20, 15, 0, 0.}, 325.274, {2006, 1, 20, 18, 
  0, 0.}, 325.658, {2006, 1, 20, 21, 0, 0.}, 326.558, {2006, 1, 21, 0,
   0, 0.}, 327.196, {2006, 1, 21, 3, 0, 0.}, 323.771, {2006, 1, 21, 6,
   0, 0.}, 316.523, {2006, 1, 21, 9, 0, 0.}, 316.252, {2006, 1, 21, 
  12, 0, 0.}, 321.72, {2006, 1, 21, 15, 0, 0.}, 324.336, {2006, 1, 21,
   18, 0, 0.}, 327.127, {2006, 1, 21, 21, 0, 0.}, 328.491, {2006, 1, 
  22, 0, 0, 0.}, 328.535, {2006, 1, 22, 3, 0, 0.}, 322.131, {2006, 1, 
  22, 6, 0, 0.}, 318.04, {2006, 1, 22, 9, 0, 0.}, 316.22, {2006, 1, 
  22, 12, 0, 0.}, 321.768, {2006, 1, 22, 15, 0, 0.}, 322.051, {2006, 
  1, 22, 18, 0, 0.}, 323.318, {2006, 1, 22, 21, 0, 
  0.}, 324.169, {2006, 1, 23, 0, 0, 0.}, 324.497, {2006, 1, 23, 3, 0, 
  0.}, 322.241, {2006, 1, 23, 6, 0, 0.}, 317.922, {2006, 1, 23, 9, 0, 
  0.}, 317.827, {2006, 1, 23, 12, 0, 0.}, 318.877, {2006, 1, 23, 15, 
  0, 0.}, 321.213, {2006, 1, 23, 18, 0, 0.}, 322.607, {2006, 1, 23, 
  21, 0, 0.}, 325.508, {2006, 1, 24, 0, 0, 0.}, 326.516, {2006, 1, 24,
   3, 0, 0.}, 325.44, {2006, 1, 24, 6, 0, 0.}, 322.301, {2006, 1, 24, 
  9, 0, 0.}, 320.571, {2006, 1, 24, 12, 0, 0.}, 323.99, {2006, 1, 24, 
  15, 0, 0.}, 325.769, {2006, 1, 24, 18, 0, 0.}, 325.893, {2006, 1, 
  24, 21, 0, 0.}, 323.95, {2006, 1, 25, 0, 0, 0.}, 322.063, {2006, 1, 
  25, 3, 0, 0.}, 317.175, {2006, 1, 25, 6, 0, 0.}, 311.124, {2006, 1, 
  25, 9, 0, 0.}, 310.832, {2006, 1, 25, 12, 0, 0.}, 317.104, {2006, 1,
   25, 15, 0, 0.}, 319.588, {2006, 1, 25, 18, 0, 0.}, 321.886, {2006, 
  1, 25, 21, 0, 0.}, 324.605, {2006, 1, 26, 0, 0, 0.}, 325.571, {2006,
   1, 26, 3, 0, 0.}, 319.892, {2006, 1, 26, 6, 0, 0.}, 312.419, {2006,
   1, 26, 9, 0, 0.}, 311.632, {2006, 1, 26, 12, 0, 
  0.}, 317.151, {2006, 1, 26, 15, 0, 0.}, 315.756, {2006, 1, 26, 18, 
  0, 0.}, 309.114, {2006, 1, 26, 21, 0, 0.}, 308.152, {2006, 1, 27, 0,
   0, 0.}, 307.869, {2006, 1, 27, 3, 0, 0.}, 306.179, {2006, 1, 27, 6,
   0, 0.}, 304.344, {2006, 1, 27, 9, 0, 0.}, 310.731, {2006, 1, 27, 
  12, 0, 0.}, 312.042, {2006, 1, 27, 15, 0, 0.}, 315.486, {2006, 1, 
  27, 18, 0, 0.}, 319.399, {2006, 1, 27, 21, 0, 0.}, 326.018, {2006, 
  1, 28, 0, 0, 0.}, 323.422, {2006, 1, 28, 3, 0, 0.}, 321.549, {2006, 
  1, 28, 6, 0, 0.}, 315.104, {2006, 1, 28, 9, 0, 0.}, 318.588, {2006, 
  1, 28, 12, 0, 0.}, 324.495, {2006, 1, 28, 15, 0, 
  0.}, 329.223, {2006, 1, 28, 18, 0, 0.}, 331.212, {2006, 1, 28, 21, 
  0, 0.}, 331.474, {2006, 1, 29, 0, 0, 0.}, 333.785, {2006, 1, 29, 3, 
  0, 0.}, 327.536, {2006, 1, 29, 6, 0, 0.}, 321.733, {2006, 1, 29, 9, 
  0, 0.}, 318.309, {2006, 1, 29, 12, 0, 0.}, 325.799, {2006, 1, 29, 
  15, 0, 0.}, 327.442, {2006, 1, 29, 18, 0, 0.}, 327.955, {2006, 1, 
  29, 21, 0, 0.}, 328.15, {2006, 1, 30, 0, 0, 0.}, 330.915, {2006, 1, 
  30, 3, 0, 0.}, 326.628, {2006, 1, 30, 6, 0, 0.}, 317.78, {2006, 1, 
  30, 9, 0, 0.}, 316.483, {2006, 1, 30, 12, 0, 0.}, 322.661, {2006, 1,
   30, 15, 0, 0.}, 327.509, {2006, 1, 30, 18, 0, 0.}, 330.479, {2006, 
  1, 30, 21, 0, 0.}, 333.422, {2006, 1, 31, 0, 0, 0.}, 335.805, {2006,
   1, 31, 3, 0, 0.}, 329.932, {2006, 1, 31, 6, 0, 0.}, 322.188, {2006,
   1, 31, 9, 0, 0.}, 322.895, {2006, 1, 31, 12, 0, 
  0.}, 330.111, {2006, 1, 31, 15, 0, 0.}, 333.34, {2006, 1, 31, 18, 0,
   0.}, 334.173, {2006, 1, 31, 21, 0, 0.}}

how to find mean of day and  month, years value? ... this is only month data.

Comment: Dear @BatbuyanMGL, please do not dump big amounts of unformatted data code like this. In any case, your data set looks like it isn't set up properly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your data are unbalanced and not arranged appropriately; you need to `Partition` it into date-value pairs. There is also an errant opening curly bracket at the beginning of your definition of `data`. I have stripped this out.

You can collect together all the values that occur on the same day using `GatherBy`, and then apply the `Mean` or other function you want to apply on each row of data, after stripping out the dates.

```
Mean /@ (GatherBy[Partition[data, 2], #[[1, 1 ;; 3]] &][[All, All, 2]])
```

Let's unpack this single-liner. `Partition` just organises the data into date-value pairs. The `GatherBy` statement then groups each of these pairs if the first few elements of the date are the same. The specification `1;;3` covers daily data. If you wanted monthly averages, you would use `1;;2` instead.  The `[[All, All, 2]]` bit just ensures that you are only operating on the values, not the dates, and then you can `Map` (`/@`) `Mean`, or whatever other function you desire, to each row of values.

Other questions you might find helpful include [this one](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/30712/8), [this one](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/7085/8), and anything else relevant in [this search](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=GatherBy+date).

Note that version 10 will have some more sophisticated functionality for manipulating time series, including [this](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TimeSeriesAggregate.html).

Comment: Heading for http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/badges/57/reversal? That would be hilarious. Please comment if there are changes to the answer you think would be warranted to get there.

Answer (score 0):

Other than what's given in the answer above...

Fastest (both computationally, and logically) way to get `Mean` and other stats on `DateList` data (in form {yyyy,mm,dd}) is to convert it to absolute time, then do your operation on integers, then convert the answer(s) back to date(s), which will give you 6 positions, since it'll also return time, which you effectively cut off with `Part[;;3]`:

```
dates={{2016,1,1},{2016,6,1},{2017,1,1},{2017,6,1}};
DateList[Mean[AbsoluteTime/@dates]][[;;3]]
```

returns `{2016, 9, 15}`